# Find names in string using regex without including first names if second name is present

Tags: php, regex, keyword-spotting

I have a string and a list of names that I compare the string against using `preg_match_all` which returns the matches. However in the list of names, some names are first-name OR last-name only while others are both. See my example below.

```
$names = 'jon|jon snow|lana|smith|lana smith|megan';
$string = 'Jon Snow and Lana Smith met up with Lana and Megan.';
preg_match_all("~\b($names)\b~i", $string, $matches);
```

The above example with my current expression returns all the names. Which isn't what I want.

What I want returned: **jon snow, lana smith, lana, megan.**

What I don't want returned: **jon, smith**

Comment: Why do you have names you don't want in the `$names`?

Comment: i would like to see the real world application.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you somehow remove non name words, then split on a regex of more than one space.  What you would be left with would be a name.  But alas, I don't see an easy way to distinguish between name nouns and other types of nouns.

Comment: @4castle All names in $names are wanted. Im checking models names against content. Some models are single words only. 

A real world example would be the model "Kat" and model "Kat Dior". Two seperate individuals.

Comment: Just to expand on that given real world example. If I have content that contains the words "Kat Dior", both "Kat" and "Kat Dior" would be returned as matches. Which is the problem.

But "Kat" is still very much a wanted name to search for.

Comment: that still makes little sense in a real world senerio. simply search for kate or Dior

Comment: You have to order your alternation differently, put the longest possible patterns first.

Comment: @Dagon that would return incorrect matches for way too many models.

I have an array of model names, all names are wanted, some names are 1 word and some are not. There are hundreds of models and thousands of strings.

"Kat" is a model and "Kat Dior" is another. A string containing the words "Kat Dior" should ONLY return Kate Dior as a match. Because Kat and Kat Dior are two different people. With that being said if both are found in a single string separately both should be returned.

Does that make more sense. It needs to be precise given the amount of content it will sift through.

Comment: @SebastianProske I thought something along those lines but wasn't sure how to do that? Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: @Jesse for your sample: `jon snow|lana smith|jon|lana|smith|megan`

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't think of it like that. So by ordering the list of names by longest to shortest I can match the longest sets of names first. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [negative lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

For example, `jon(?! snow)` matches `"jon"`, but only if `" snow"` does not follow.

```
$names = 'jon(?! snow)|jon snow|lana(?! smith)|(?<!lana )smith|lana smith|megan';
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bD1wU7/1).

Another possibility - less explicit but with comparable results - is to ensure that the "composite" terms are tested first:

```
$names = 'jon snow|jon|lana smith|lana|smith|megan';
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aL8jT9/1).

Comment: Thanks Tim, this is exactly what I was looking for. Just didn't know how to word it. Works well.